# Why isn't there a format that like fat binaries will allow an executable to run with different instruction sets but on the same architecture?

Tags: architecture, compiler-construction, format, executable, file-format

It would make it possible to have optimized binaries for several processors.

If done right it wouldn't even need to duplicate much data.

Comment: There are attempts, e.g. FatELF: http://icculus.org/fatelf/

Comment: That's for different architectures, not same arch with different instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get the question right, you're asking a format with builds optimized for different CPU's of the same family.

The downside of this is that there is need for more testing. You're not likely to find anything, but it's so embarresing if your final build mistakenly contains the wrong version of the code.

The gains may also not be that great: usually compilers optimize such that they avoid known performance issues with common CPU architectures. You may argue that your software will benefit from SSE instructions on new hardware, but if your application is so demanding that it needs SSE instructions even on recent hardware, your software will be close to unusable on older CPUs.

Comment: My assumption **was** a gain of the order 5-10%. Which is usually not enough to be noticable. Anyway, my argument is that many people like me, see little to gain, so there is little demand, so there is no format. Which tries to answer the question. What kind answer where you hoping to get? It's not because it's technically impossible or anything.